# NSButton raising click event on mouseup

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsbutton

I am looking for an NSButton raising the click event on mouseup, even if the mouse down has been made outside the button. 
Do you have any idea to get this behavior?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Moving the mouse outside a control before releasing the button allows the user to cancel the action.

I would think the only way to do that would be to intercept all events and handle all click tracking and movement tracking yourself.

However, it would result in a very unexpected interface behavior, so you should consider carefully why you need to do that.